# shelve module does not work with "with" statement

Tags: python, persistence, shelve

I'm trying to use the shelve module in python, and I'm trying to combine it with the "with" statement, but when trying to do that I get the following error:

```
with shelve.open('shelve', 'c') as shlv_file:
    shlv_file['title']    = 'The main title of my app'
    shlv_file['datatype'] = 'data type int32'
    shlv_file['content']  = 'Lorem ipsum'
    shlv_file['refs']     = '<htppsa: asda.com>'

print(shlv_file)
```

The following error is raised:

```
 with shelve.open('shelve', 'c') as shlv_file:
AttributeError: DbfilenameShelf instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

Although doing this way:

```
shlv_file = shelve.open('data/shelve', 'c')
shlv_file['title']    = 'The main title of my app'
shlv_file['datatype'] = 'data type int32'
shlv_file['content']  = 'Lorem ipsum'
shlv_file['refs']     = '<htppsa: asda.com>'
shlv_file.close()

shlv_file = shelve.open('data/shelve', 'c')
shlv_file['new_filed'] = 'bla bla bla'
print(shlv_file)
```

No error is raised, and the output is the one that is expected. What is the problem with the first syntax ? I was watching a python course in which the instructor uses the first version without any problems.

Comment: What's your version of Python? According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.Shelf), context manager support (the `with` block) was added in 3.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand what the purpose of `with` is used for. It is basically used to automatically handle setup and cleanup of objects it is called with, provided *those objects support the use of such setup and cleanup functions*. In particular, the object for setup is the `__enter__` function, and the teardown equivalent is the `__exit__` function. Here's an example:

```
In [355]: class Foo():
     ...:     def __enter__(self):
     ...:         print("Start!")
     ...:         return self
     ...:     def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
     ...:         print("End!")
     ...:
```

And, now instantiate an object of `Foo` with `with...as`:

```
In [356]: with Foo() as x:
     ...:     print(x)
     ...:     
Start!
<__main__.Foo object at 0x1097f5da0>
End!
```

As you see, `with...as` will compulsorily call these setup/teardown methods, and if they're missing, an `AttributeError` will be raised because an attempt to call  a non-existent instance method is made.

It's the same with your `shelve` object - it doesn't have an `__exit__` method defined in its class, so using `with` will not work.

---

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.Shelf), support for the context manager was added from version 3.4 and onwards. If the context manager does not work, that would mean your version is older.

Comment: Well I understand your explanation. What Im still confused is that why it seems to work fine on the instructors tutorial that Im watching and it doesnt work on my machine ?

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but `shelve` does support a context manager in recent versions (3.4+), which is why Pj- may have seen it in a tutorial.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Thanks for noting this. I do not know about `shelve`, so I just assumed it wasn't implemented.

Comment: @Pj- As Paulo pointed out, its to do with your python version.

Comment: I think my python version is not up to date. I will try that @PauloAlmeida

Comment: Thanks for the help @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ